# my wife just got an iphone 3GS. we both have apple IDs, but her iTunes on her iPhone shows my username

Tags: iphone

my wife just got an iphone 3GS. we both have apple IDs and use a macbook together, but her iTunes on her iPhone shows my username and the credit amount that I have. When buying a song or an app, my user account info pops up. How can we have her username and log in information appear on her iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same user on your MacBook? If so, you're probably using the same iTunes too, which probably is set to your Apple ID. To use a different ID, you need to switch accounts every time you sync the iPhones. To sign out, choose "Store" > "Sign out" in the iTunes menu bar.

Thankfully, this whole hassle will be over when iOS 5 is released.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply authorize both accounts to run on your computers at home (store--> authorize this computer), and then, on the actual IPhone, go to settings--> store--> log out, then just log back in using her account.